# floated inner <div> flows out of surrounding <div>

Tags: html, css-float

Please help me to understand why the `image`-`div` of the following code flows out of the `box`-`div`.

```
<body>
    <div id="box" style="border: 2px solid green;">
            <div id="image" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: red; float: left;"></div>
            <div id="text" style="background: yellow;">This is some text</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In other words, I expected the green border to fully enclose both inner `div`s and not only the yellow one.

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html for further explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a children its floating the parent doesn't wrap it. You can use two solutions for this:

```
#box{
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

Or

```
#box{
     float:left;
}
```

You can also use `display:inline-block` for the `#box` but that doesn't work on IE6

Answer (score 2):

setting overflow to hidden is not always an ideal solution, as if you do have content which is larger than the container, it will not be displayed.

by adding a clearing element at the bottom of the container, you should see that the floated elements fit inside the parent.

```
<body>
    <div id="box" style="border: 2px solid green;">
            <div id="image" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: red; float: left;"></div>
            <div id="text" style="background: yellow;">This is some text</div>

            <div style="clear: left; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Obviously, you'll want to make a generic class for this and set the CSS in an external stylesheet - but the principle works.

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements are allowed to extend beyond their parent element.  To keep the floated element inside the containing element, you will need to add an empty element at the end that clears the float:

So inside the element with `id="box"`, add something like this:

```
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
```

Comment: Adding elements is not needed and just adds clutter. The other solutions are better.

Comment: @Rob: I'm assuming that by "other solutions" you mean the single highest-voted one, since two of the other solutions propose exactly what I do here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an element to "clear" the floated object, using `style="clear: left;"`